# HTML: JQuery Every selected image appears in same container

Tags: jquery, html

So basically I'm not a web developer and I really don't know how to talk about this issue correctly. So I'm building an arrow selector which has many selection fields and I have a div with pictures, the pictures changes within a user-selected field, so right here I have some bugs which appear when the user tries to select some options. For example, if I would select one field of arrow color, the image in the div changes, but in the wrong container( Every selected image appears in same container )

[My Selector BUG GIF example:](https://gyazo.com/fe2f526c132048856653aff8a5ff5a01)

[The website](http://falco.ee/arrow/eng/) with the selector which is functions well, you can see that every select option works good with the image.

My JQuery code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript"
src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" > < /script> < script language = "javascript" >

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".dk_options_inner li").mouseover(function() {
            $(this).parent(".dk_options_inner").find("li").removeClass("dk_option_current");
            $(this).addClass("dk_option_current");
            $(this).parent(".dk_options_inner").find("li").removeClass("dk_option_current selected");
            $(this).addClass("dk_option_current selected");
            $(this).closest(".dk_container").find(".dk_label").text($(this).text());
            var tip = $(this).find("a").attr("data-image");
            $("#arrow-img-tip").find("img").attr("src", tip);
        });
        $(".dk_options_inner li").click(function() {
            $("#dk_container_arrow-tip").attr('class', 'dk_container dk_theme_black');
            $("#dk_container_arrow-front").attr('class', 'dk_container dk_theme_black');
            $("#dk_container_arrow-nok").attr('class', 'dk_container dk_theme_black');
        });
    });

</script>
```

My HTML code:

```
<div class="arrow-section arrow-col-3">
    <div class="arrow-section-left">
        <div id="arrow-select-tip">
            <div class="arrow-selectbox-wrapper">
                <h4><span>Point</span></h4>
                <div class="dk_container dk_theme_black" id="dk_container_arrow-tip" tabindex="1" style="display: block;"><a onclick="uzdarom_tip_menu();" class="dk_toggle" style="width: 129px;"><span class="dk_label">TopHat 3D 20g</span></a>
                    <div class="dk_options">
                        <ul class="dk_options_inner">
                            <li class="dk_option_current selected"><a data-dk-dropdown-value="1" data-image="http://www.falco.ee/arrow/eng/img/teravikud/steel_field.png">TopHat 3D 20g</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="2" data-image="http://www.falco.ee/arrow/eng/img/teravikud/brass_bullet.png">TopHat 3D 70g</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="4" data-image="http://www.falco.ee/arrow/eng/img/teravikud/3D.png">TopHat 3D 100g</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="6" data-image="http://www.falco.ee/arrow/eng/img/teravikud/brass_3d.png">Brass 3D 70g</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="7" data-image="http://www.falco.ee/arrow/eng/img/teravikud/brass_3d.png">Brass 3D 100g</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="9" data-image="http://www.falco.ee/arrow/eng/img/teravikud/brass_bullet.png">Brass Bullet 70g</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="10" data-image="http://www.falco.ee/arrow/eng/img/teravikud/brass_bullet.png">Brass Bullet 100g</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="12" data-image="http://www.falco.ee/arrow/eng/img/teravikud/steel_field.png">Steel Field 70g</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="13" data-image="http://www.falco.ee/arrow/eng/img/teravikud/steel_field.png">Steel Field 100g</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow-section-right">
            <div id="arrow-select-nok">
                <div class="arrow-selectbox-wrapper">
                    <h4><span>Nock color</span></h4>
                    <div class="arrow-selectbox-container">
                        <div class="dk_container dk_theme_black" id="dk_container_arrow-nok" tabindex="1" style="display: block;"><a onclick="uzdarom_color_menu();" class="dk_toggle" style="width: 69px;"><span class="dk_label">Black</span></a>
                            <div class="dk_options">
                                <ul class="dk_options_inner">
                                    <li class="dk_option_current"><a data-dk-dropdown-value="1" data-image="http://www.falco.ee/arrow/eng/img/nokid/black.png">Black</a></li>
                                    <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="2" data-image="http://www.falco.ee/arrow/eng/img/nokid/lime.png">Lime</a></li>
                                    <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="3" data-image="http://www.falco.ee/arrow/eng/img/nokid/orange.png">Orange</a></li>
                                    <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="4" data-image="http://www.falco.ee/arrow/eng/img/nokid/red.png">Red</a></li>
                                    <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="5" data-image="http://www.falco.ee/arrow/eng/img/nokid/white.png">White</a></li>
                                    <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="6" data-image="http://www.falco.ee/arrow/eng/img/nokid/yellow.png">Yellow</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <select id="arrow-nok" name="nok" data-direction="down" class="arrow-dropdown black dk" tabindex="1" style="display: none;">
                            <option selected="selected" value="1">Black</option>
                            <option value="2">Lime</option>
                            <option value="3">Orange</option>
                            <option value="4">Red</option>
                            <option value="5">White</option>
                            <option value="6">Yellow</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all of the images appear in the wrong container because according to this line in your script

```
 $("#arrow-img-tip").find("img").attr("src", tip);
```

all images are displayed in the same div with the id `arrow-img-tip`. Instead, you have to address different containers depending on the part of the image you want to select.

Comment: How can I address it?

Comment: You could set another data attribute to the parent ul element (so you only have to do it once), e.g data-container="arrow-img-front" and so on for the corresponding images.

Comment: Can we continue in the chat?